# How to initialized a view model that needs data from a remote server in MAUI and how to do if there is an exception?

Tags: c#, maui

I have a view model that needs to load some data from a server to populate a list view.

But I don't know how should to do that. this is my first try:

```cs
public MainViewModel(IRepository paramRepository)
{
    try
    {
        MyItems = paramRepository.GetItems();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", "Items not populated. Try later.", "OK").Wait();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the alert it not shown, I get a black screen because the page is not shown.

I have also read that it is not a good practice to use the constructor for complex instantiations, that is better to use a factory. But anyway, if I get an error when I try to load the items, I guess that I will have the same problem, I will can not show the alert to the user to warn about the problem.

Perhaps there is a better way to handle this, and it is not try to show an alert but to do another thing.

In summary, I would like to know how is a good way to instantiate a view model that needs to get resources from a remote server or some resources that could make get an exception.

Here is the full code of the application:

AppShell code-behind:

```cs
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

AppShell.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MyApplication.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Views"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    
    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainView}"
        Route="MainPage" />
    
</Shell>
```

App.cs:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    
        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

MauiProgram.cs:

```cs
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });        
    builder.Services.AddTransient<MainView>();
    builder.Services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
           
    MauiApp miApp = builder.Build();
        
    return miApp;
}
```

MainView code-behind:

```cs
public partial class MainView : ContentPage
{
    public MainView(MainViewModel paramViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = paramViewModel;
        _viewModel = paramViewModel;
    }
}
```

MainViewModel:

```cs
public  class MainViewModel
{
    #region variables de clase
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    #endregion variables de clase

    public MainViewModel(IRepository paramRepository)
    {
        try
        {
            _repository = paramRepository;
    
            //What happen if I get an exception here?
            Task.Run(MyCollection = new ObservableCollection(await _repsitory.GetItems()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK").Wait();
        }
    }
    
    public ObservableCollection<MyType> MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
}
```

At startup it is tried to open the main view and instante the main view model.

If I have to try to get the resources before the view model is created, the option it is to do it in the AppShell class, in the App class or in the MauiApp() class.

In any of this three options, if I get an exception trying the resources, how to warn to the user or how to handle it without stopping the application?

Comment: You can load the resources before you instantiate the ViewModel and pass them either into the constructor or you can use a setter method on the ViewModel once the data has been loaded. Alerts can only be shown after the MainPage has been set, which means that you also cannot do this in the constructor of the ViewModel if the ViewModel is instantiated inside the constructor of the MainPage. Please show all relevant code, especially where the ViewModel constructor is called.

Comment: Correct. It's not a good practice. Simply do it in a different method. For an example, "OnAppearing" event.

Comment: @ewerspej I understand i should to load resources before instante the view model. But for example, in a WPF application, I have the main view model. When should I load the resources? in the App() method in the app.xaml.cs file? If this is true, how could warning to user that there is a problem? For example loading resources from a remote server?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía Like I mentioned before, you should show all the relevant code as it's easier to talk about that than having a discussion about a description.

Comment: I have added all the code of the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do.

```cs
public MyClassVm()
{
}

public async override void Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Loading = true;
        try
        {
            base.Appearing(sender, e);
            var feedList = await Data.GetUserFeed();
            Feed = new ObservableCollection<FeedContentDTO>(feedList.FeedContents);
        }
        finally
        {
            Loading = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        AppExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

So, the difference is that it is happening in an async method which gets called after the constructor. I am using an Appearing method from our base VM (which gets called by a VM utility class we made) but you could do it in NavigatedTo or some other method which might be more suitable.

Comment: Why do you have a `try-finally` block inside of a `try-catch` block? You could simply remove the inner `try`-block, move the `finally` one level up and set `IsLoading = false` in there.